# SQL Use table column for IN clause

Tags: sql

I need to select and count some rows where a column is `IN` a dataset provided from another table.

Easier to show you the query than explain:

```
SELECT 
    t.code, t.description,
    (SELECT count(id)
     FROM web_vehicles
     WHERE sale_type IN (t.query)) vehicle_count
FROM 
    search_sale_type t
GROUP BY 
    t.id
```

So the `sale_type` could be multiple values for the same type, hence why I need the `WHERE IN`. How can I make it so that `t.query` could be for example `car,cars`.

Currently only adding something like `car` works, adding `car,cars` makes that part fail.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and your expected results?

Comment: And tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Notice that inside `IN` you can use select from another table `fld in (select val from table)`

Comment: Please note that you have to group by every selected column that is not part of the function you might use.

Comment: I'd guess the sub-query condition should be correlated, i.e. `where sale_type = t.sale_type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would put use the *query* not a string representation:

```
SELECT t.code, t.description,
       (SELECT COUNT(id)
        FROM web_vehicles
        WHERE sale_type IN (SELECT ot.sale_type FROM othertable ot)
       ) vehicle_count
FROM search_sale_type t
GROUP BY t.id;
```

However, the structure of this query is suspicious.  I don't understand the outer aggregation.  It seems like `search_sale_type` should already have one row per `id`.